Show more minor/major tick labels when using log10 scale with matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

## making data
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012],
                        'numbers': [2684044.85, 4005117.02, 3046403.46, 6413495.07, 14885525.21, 5152235.33, 4040850.37,
                                    4616841.13, 4862062.25, 4702041.0, 5201620.42, 4405820.64, 1454650.88]})

## making plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,7))
# plot x and y1
ax.plot('year', 'numbers', 'x-', data=temp_df)
ax.set_yscale('log', base=10)

This produces

There are no minor tick-labels on y-axis, with other data I get more major- and minor tick-labels. How to force show more tick-labels on y-axis in log-10 scale dynamically without hardcoding the numbers?
my package versions are below on Python 3.10.12
matplotlib                     3.5.2
matplotlib-inline              0.1.6
pandas                         1.4.4


There are minor ticks, just no minor tick labels.

yes, labels is what I had meant. i want to show more labels for the plots to be more readable. i will now update the question.

Perhaps helpful.

I'm pretty sure you can change this behaviour with the minor_thresholds keyword argument https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatter

This grabs the bounds of your current axis and turns on minor tick labels within that range.  It will only turn on minor tick labels if the number of major labels is less than three.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import pandas as pd


temp_df = pd.DataFrame({
  'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
     2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012],
  'numbers': [2684044.85, 4005117.02, 3046403.46, 6413495.07, 14885525.21, 
     5152235.33, 4040850.37, 4616841.13, 4862062.25, 4702041.0, 5201620.42, 
     4405820.64, 1454650.88]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,7))
ax.set_yscale('log', base=10)
ax.plot('year', 'numbers', 'x-', data=temp_df)
low, high = ax.get_ylim()
ticks = [t for t in ax.get_yticks() if low <= t <= high]

if len(ticks) < 3:
    m_ticker = ticker.LogFormatterSciNotation(
        labelOnlyBase=False, minor_thresholds=(low, high)
    )
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(m_ticker)

